# Can I get a Rust array's length with only a type, not a concrete variable?

Tags: arrays, rust, dependent-type, constant-expression

I want to rewrite the following C++ code into Rust:

```cpp
using storage = array<int, 3>;
const size_t storage_len = sizeof(storage) / sizeof(storage::value_type);
```

How can I get that constant length value without a concrete variable?

As motivation, although it may seem trivial, I want to print the array's element count without declaring a variable. I know I could use a constant value or declare a dummy variable, but I wonder how Rust can preserve C++ code.

I admit *without a concrete variable* is not clear. I want to achieve the above C++ feature, but this explanation can be misleading. I'm curious if there is any way to get the array's element type.

Comment: Your question is a little bit misleading. What do you mean by *"without a concrete variable"*? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: To everybody who says "just use `size_of(x)/size_of(y)`, please try `size_of::<[(); 3]>() / size_of::<()>()`

Comment: @hellow They did not say `x` and `y` but `[i32; 3]` and `i32`, so that's totally fine.

Comment: I would like to know why you need such feature.

Comment: I think he wants to know about const generics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rust now has support for const generics. I left the old answer so people have an idea why someone might have asked this in the first place.

**New Answer since Rust 1.51**:

```rust
pub trait Length {
    const LEN: usize;
}

impl<T, const LENGTH: usize> Length for [T; LENGTH] {
    const LEN: usize = LENGTH;
}
// ...

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <[String; 1]>::LEN);
}
```

**Old Answer**:

I understand that you want to retrieve the array length from the type information alone. Rust does not have built-in PI types (a.k.a. *const generics*). This means generic parameters which are *not* types (like an integer for an array length) are currently not supported by the language.

There is [an issue tracking this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580) and we are likely to see support for it in the future, though not the near future.

If you have to, you can work around that limitation by implementing a trait for each type:

```
trait GetLength {
    fn len() -> usize;
}

impl<T> GetLength for [T; 0] {
    fn len() -> usize {
        0
    }
}

impl<T> GetLength for [T; 1] {
    fn len() -> usize {
        1
    }
}

// ...

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <[String; 1]>::len());
}
```

Macros can help prevent repetitive typing:

```
trait GetLength {
    fn len() -> usize;
}

macro_rules! impl_get_length {
    ($v:expr) => {
        impl<T> GetLength for [T; $v] {
            fn len() -> usize {
                $v
            }
        }
    };
}

impl_get_length!{ 0 }
impl_get_length!{ 1 }

// ...

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <[String; 1]>::len());
}
```

Crates like [`typenum`](https://crates.io/crates/typenum) also help to provide some support for const generics within the existing language.

Answer (score 7):

In Rust, you can get the size of a type with [`std::mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.size_of.html), so you can get the length of your array type the same way as in C++:

```
use std::mem::size_of;

type Storage = [i32; 3];

fn main() {
    println!("Length: {}", size_of::<Storage>() / size_of::<i32>());
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=924682f5b163f4ce5052efd4379fe481&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

However this requires knowing the type of items stored in the array. I don't know of a way to get that without instantiating a variable.

Comment: Note that this is a divide by zero for `()`.

Comment: `size_of::<<Storage as Index<usize>>::Output>`, maybe?

Comment: Nope, scratch that. Arrays depend on an unsized coercion to implement `Index`. I don't know of a way to express the item type.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
use std::mem;
use std::ops::Deref;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(5, num_elems::<[i32; 5]>());
}

fn num_elems<T>() -> usize 
where 
    T: 'static, 
    &'static T: IntoIterator,
    <&'static T as IntoIterator>::Item: Deref,
    <<&'static T as IntoIterator>::Item as Deref>::Target: Sized,
{
    fn inner<S, I>() -> usize 
    where 
        I: Deref,
        <I as Deref>::Target: Sized,
    { 
        mem::size_of::<S>() / mem::size_of::<I::Target>()
    }

    inner::<T, <&'static T as IntoIterator>::Item>()
}
```

This will work for any array up to 32 elements, and will panic if the array element type is zero-sized. Also, you can use other things, besides array types, and I have no idea what it will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html):

```
let storage_len = std::mem::size_of::<[i32; 3]>() / std::mem::size_of::<i32>();
```

Comment: @Stargateur This could be used in generic code, though I can't really come up with an actual use case either.

Answer (score -1):

[Arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) coerce to [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html), so any method available on slices are also available on arrays. Like [`len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.len):

```
let v = [0u32; 128];
assert_eq!(128, v.len());
```

Comment: You do not answer the question: the OP asks to have the result *without a concrete variable*.