# get rust named array length right from the type without a concrete variable

Tags: arrays, rust, types

I have named a 3-sized array type `Sequence`. From objects of this type, the entries of a `Vec` will successively be calculated by a finite automaton. After the automaton has run, the `Vec` is guaranteed to either contain the length of `Sequence` (=3) or in some cases one more than that (=4) items.

I try to use `Vec::with_capacity` to fit the `Vec` to the maximum possible memory requirements (=4). To avoid useless allocation and dropping of the `Vec`, I want to allocate it once before any `Sequence` object arrives:

```rust
type Sequence = [ f64; 3 ];

fn main() {
    let mut accumulator: Vec<f64> = Vec::with_capacity( Sequence.len() + 1 );
    …
}
```

Of course, this code does not compile, because `.len()` only works on instances, not the type. But there is no concrete `Sequence` variable there at this preparatory stage.

I would like to avoid a hard-to-read C-like construct of the form used in:

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;
type Sequence = [ f64; 3 ];

fn main() {
    let mut accumulator: Vec<f64> = Vec::with_capacity( size_of::<Sequence>() / size_of::<f64>() + 1 );
}
```

My type should remain very simple; for generics, I have read a good answer to a similar question here: [Can I get a Rust array's length with only a type, not a concrete variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379284/can-i-get-a-rust-arrays-length-with-only-a-type-not-a-concrete-variable) But I wonder whether there is a simpler way for my quite straightforwart type `Sequence` than defining a generic trait to get the job done.

For eample, I know that I could define a `const` and use that, but it seems this would tear apart type information from the type; and if rust allows, I want to avoid that:

```rust
const SEQUENCE_LEN: usize = 3;
type Sequence = [ f64; SEQUENCE_LEN ];

fn main() {
    let mut accumulator: Vec<f64> = Vec::with_capacity( SEQUENCE_LEN + 1 );
}
```

For the same reason of keeping things together when they belong together, I do not want to simply use a literal like in `with_capacity(4)`.

Comment: You already saw all options. Either use the answer in the question you linked, or use a `const`.

Comment: As an unrelated note, it may be more performant to use [`ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/latest/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strike me as great, but another option is

```
type Sequence = [f64; 3];

pub fn get_vec() -> Vec<f64> {
    Vec::with_capacity(Sequence::default().len() + 1)
}
```

In release mode, this compiles down to exactly the same assembly as

```
type Sequence = [f64; 3];

pub fn get_vec_magic_number() -> Vec<f64> {
    Vec::with_capacity(4)
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Sequence::default().len() + 1`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Great question. The proverbial brain fart, I think.